# Cannot get update query to work with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-update

I have a simple update query just to check if update query works:

```
 this.openDBTransaction();
 Query updateQuery = session.createQuery(
         "UPDATE User AS usr SET usr.failedLogins=666 WHERE usr.id='USER_3000'"
 );

 int result = updateQuery.executeUpdate();
 this.closeDBTransaction();
```

but somehow DB is not update with desired value. `result` came as 1 so something took place but for sure not update query.

Any clue what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use @Transactional annotation so that the compiler knows that the transaction is manipulating the database, thus permits to perform Data Manipulation queries or it will simply execute it as a Data Definition Language query.
Look at the code snippet below, for example,

```
@Transactional
public Employee editEmployee(Employee employee) { //employee is the data you got through post
    return entityManager.merge(e1);

}
```

Also, the best practice is to always implement Data Access Object Interface and its implementation and define your queries in the implementation.
I hope this helps.

Comment: I have implemented that as DEO and set at `@Transactionl` but simple just `UPDATE` query there is not working.

Comment: Did you try using this.commit() ?
Please look into, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm